# Call a gRPC HTTP/2 service from a .NET Framework application without using TLS

Tags: c#, .net-core, grpc

I have a .NET Framework application which cannot be ported to net core for various reasons. Now I want to switch from Grpc.Core to Grpc.Net.Client because the first one gets [deprecated](https://grpc.io/blog/grpc-csharp-future/).

May application makes a gRPC request to a service written in C++ which does only support HTTP/2 and does not provide TLS. According to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/netstandard?view=aspnetcore-6.0#net-framework) this connection is not supported: "*Only gRPC calls over TLS are supported.*". I can confirm this so far.

Is there any way to call a gRPC HTTP/2 service from a .NET Framework application without using TLS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a `proxy service` in which you call original `gRPC with TLS`.

Than from your application call this `proxy service` which doesn't have those restrictions.

```
Your app <--> proxy service <--> gRPC
```

`Proxy service` - implemented in one language you like and exposed to your application.

This is one posibility.

Comment: Marked this as answer because there is no "code only" solution.